# Remove "X/Y players sleeping" Message Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As of Minecraft Java Edition Version 1.17, there is a rather annoying message:

[image]

That will show up above a player's hotbar whenever:

- Someone goes to sleep
- Someone stops sleeping
- The number of players on the server changes, and someone is sleeping

The message is very spammy on servers with lots of players, and I would like to disable it. Is there a way to disable this from the *server itself* (meaning either a plugin, or a setting that can be changed)? If not, can this be disabled or removed client side?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this version, but you should check the gamerules.

Comment: @AMJ The only gamerule option that applies to this is `playersSleepingPercentage`, and although disabling sleep would disable this message, that is not my intention. Setting this value to negative or 0 means 1 player will sleep through the night, any percentage above 100 will prevent sleeping through the night.